# Wait function execution completion before continuing in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

I have a function which calculates the route between two points.

```
 public ClosestPoint(waypoint,currentLocation){
     let distances = [];
     for(var i=0; i< waypoint.length;i++){
         debugger

         var rWP1 = new L.Routing.Waypoint;
         rWP1.latLng = currentLocation;    

         var rWP2 = new L.Routing.Waypoint;
         rWP2.latLng = waypoint[i];   

         var myRoute =L.Routing.mapbox('access-token');
         myRoute.route([rWP1, rWP2], function(err, routes) {
             debugger
             var distance = routes[0].summary.totalDistance;
             distances.push(distance);
         });
     }  
     var minDistance=Math.min.apply(Math, distances)
     console.log("distances "+distances);
 }
```

But the problem which I faced is that **myRoute.route()** function executes after **ClosestPoint()** execution so I am not able to get the distance properly. I want **myRoute.route()** to execute inside the for-loop and then next iteration starts.

Is it possible? If yes then how? Or is there any other solution it has?

Comment: Not sure to understand is `myRoute.route` asynchronous?

Comment: Also can you give a link about `L.Routing.mapbox()` only implementation I found was `var myRoute = L.Routing.osrmv1()`

Comment: @JSmith https://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/tutorials/alternative-routers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try To wrap this function  inside **Promise** Object

```
  function get_routes(rWP1,rWP2) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      myRoute.route([rWP1, rWP2], function (err, routes) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(routes)
        }
      });
    })
  }
```

and after that you can use **await** inside async function or you can building array of promises objects and use **Promise.all**

Answer (score 0):

We shall clear one thing up. Any function with a callback in javascript will not be synchronous. So, you need to use `async` for it.

```
async.eachSeries(waypoint, function(item, nextitem) {
    async.waterfall([
         function(callback) {
             var rWP1 = new L.Routing.Waypoint;
             rWP1.latLng = currentLocation;    
             var rWP2 = new L.Routing.Waypoint;
             rWP2.latLng = item;
             callback(null, [rWP1, rWP2]);
         },
         function(data, callback) {
             myRoute.route([rWP1, rWP2], function(err, routes) {
                  var distance = routes[0].summary.totalDistance;
                  distances.push(distance);
                  if(distances.length === waypoint.length){
                      var minDistance=Math.min.apply(Math, distances)
                      console.log("distances "+distances);
                  } else {
                      callback(null, 3); //3 is just a random value you can give
                  } 
             });
         }
    ],nextitem)         
});
```